404:NOT_FOUND after vercel deployment
My portfolio site is working fine on local host but when i deploy it on vercel,url's of my linkedin profile and github page are showing 404:NOT_FOUND error
Here is the link of my website text.Can anyone help me i am stuck here for long

I checked the site and it seems like it's working fine. Was the problem that you had a wait a while?

The links that you have added in the href are not correct. You must add //, like this after https. 
https://github.com/[username] 
similarly with LinkedIn.
<img
    src="./assets/linkedin.png"
    alt="My LinkedIn profile"
    class="icon"
    onclick="location.href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/shaileshoza/'"
/>
<img
    src="./assets/github.png"
    alt="My Github profile"
    class="icon"
    onclick="location.href='https://github.com/shailesh2503'"
/>


you did put link without ://
put this:
onclick="location.href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/shaileshoza/'"
insted of this:
onclick="location.href='https:www.linkedin.com/in/shaileshoza/'"
<img src="./assets/linkedin.png" alt="My LinkedIn profile" class="icon" onclick="location.href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/shaileshoza/'">```


The link URL seem to be the problem, your current onclick function has onclick="location.href='https:www.linkedin.com/in/shaileshoza/'" and it should be onclick="location.href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/shaileshoza/'". You need to include // after the semicolon (:) on each link as other links have the same error. Updated code below.
<img src="./assets/linkedin.png" alt="My LinkedIn profile" class="icon" onclick="location.href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/shaileshoza/'">

